# Reactive programming - observable cache

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I am rather new to reactive programming and observables, so there may be an obvious solution, but nonetheless I just cannot figure out how to make this simple caching service in javascript with observables

```
private legalIds: number[]
private personsCache: Person[] // Person has an id as a property

getPersons(ids: number[]) {
  const fromCache = personsCache.filter(p => ids.includes(p.id)) // Get the cached persons
  const newPersons = getPersons(ids.filter(id => legalIds.includes(id) && !fromCache.includes(id))) // Get the ones not already cached, if the ids are allowed

  return fromCache.concat(newPserons)
}
```

How would you implement the above chaching functionality scritly using observables? no imperative programming of storing arrays etc.

Comment: Is the answer provided fitting to you? Or do you have any questions? It's a pretty high effort to write detailed answers and I would like to have at least feedback if it's understood

Answer (score 0):

I am actually unsure about your inner recursive getPersons(..) call. But lets imagine it's a function that just returns you persons regarding some ids and it's non recursive.

```
private legalIds$: Subject<number[]> = new Subject();
private personsCache$: Subject<Person[]> = new Subject();

getPersons$(ids: number[]) {
  const fromCache$ = personsCache$.pipe(
    map(personsCache => personsCache.filter(p => ids.includes(p.id))
  );

  const newPersons$ = legalIds$.pipe(
    map(legalIds => getPersons(ids.filter(id => legalIds.includes(id) && !fromCache.includes(id)))
  );

  return combineLatest([fromCache$, newPersons$]).pipe(
    map(([fromCache, newPersons]) => fromCache.concat(newPersons))
  );
}
```

*- Most of the times if you have/need a recursive behavior in synchronus programming, you can solve this in rx by using scan, because of it's state*

*- If I could understand the usecase/szenario a bit more it should be possible not to require onto a getPersons$ call. Normally you can also provide an Observable (like public persons$) that uses an ids$ Observable/Subject (that is given your getPersons function).*